# Log in function broke

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Trying to accomplish a simple login form that redirects the user to index.php where only members are allowed. It worked fine when I were using mysql but when I switched my codes to mysqli it seems that I just can't get the function to work.

What happens when I click login: The input fields resets.

What have I done to solve this:

I have sent my codes to a friend and when he tried the login function it worked fine for him.
He can't find any errors in the code as well.
I have set "report all errors", I have recreated my database, created new users with full privileges, went through my codes a couple of time without having the success to tell what's wrong. Hopefully someone more trained than me can give me a good reason why my code does not work.

Database structure:
phpMyAdmin

Server version: 5.6.20

DB Name: websecurity
Tables: 2

login: username, password, email, fname, lname

guestbook: username, comment

Code for the login function, login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<p><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
<h4>Login</h4>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

//Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "member", "samsung", "websecurity");

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
die("Connect failed: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
//Submitt pushed
if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$username= strip_tags($_POST['user']);
$password= strip_tags($_POST['pass']);

$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);


// Prepare
$sql = "SELECT username,password FROM login WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt) {
        die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
    } 
//BIND
$bind_result = $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows === 1){
header("location: index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong name or password. I won't tell you!!";
}


$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" class="form-container">
<div class="form-title"><h2>Log In</h2></div>
<div class="form-title">Username</div>
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="user" /><br />
<div class="form-title">Password</div>
<input class="form-field" type="password" name="pass" /><br />
<div class="submit-container">
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
</div>
</form>
<p>Welcome to this top secret, splendid, intelligent and very fabulous website.
If you would like to use our services we kindly ask you to register as a member first.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if it will be to any help but here's the code for the redirection destination, index.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
    header("location:login.php");
} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html class="no-js"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Secret Society</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,500,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-wrapper">


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center templatemo-logo margin-top-20">
                <h2>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>!</h2> <h4>Glad that you made it in to our secret society. Feel free to check out our
                products and stay around for as long as you wish.</h4>


            </div>



        <div class="image-section">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="images/zoom-bg-1.jpg" id="menu-img" class="main-img inactive" alt="">
                        <img src="images/zoom-bg-2.jpg" id="products-img" class="inactive" alt="Product">
                        <img src="images/zoom-bg-3.jpg" id="services-img"  class="inactive" alt="Services">
                        <img src="images/zoom-bg-4.jpg" id="about-img" class="inactive" alt="About">
                        <img src="images/zoom-bg-5.jpg" id="contact-img" class="inactive" alt="Contact">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 templatemo-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="templatemo-content">

                            <section id="menu-section" class="active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-bottom-20">
                                        <a href="#products" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>
                                                <h2>Products</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-bottom-20">
                                        <a href="#services" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                                                <h2>Messages</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-bottom-20">
                                        <a href="#about" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                                <h2>About</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 margin-bottom-20">
                                        <a class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                <h2><a href="logout.php">Logout, don't leave us!</a></h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>



                                </div>
                            </section><!-- /.menu-section -->    
                            <section id="products-section" class="inactive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 margin-bottom-20">
                                        <div class="black-bg col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <h2>Something</h2>
                                            <p>Some texts here, and some texts over there!</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="black-bg col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <h2>Over there!</h2>
                                            <p> What was that?! I don't know.......</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6  pull-right">
                                        <a href="#menu" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <h2>Back to menu</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section><!-- /.product-section -->    
                            <section id="services-section" class="inactive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 black-bg">
                                            <h2>Leave a message darling!</h2>
                                            <!--Leave a message-->
        <form action='guest_process.php' method='post'>

        Name: <input style="color:black;" type="text" name='username' value="<?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>" readonly>



        <p>Message: </p>
        <p><textarea style="color:black;" name='comment'></textarea></p>
        <hr>

        <p><input style="color:black;" type='submit' name='submit' value='Post'></p>



        </form>


                                           </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6  pull-right">
                                        <a href="#menu" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <h2>Back to menu</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section><!-- /.services-section -->    
                            <section id="about-section" class="inactive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="black-bg col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <h2 class="text-center">About Us</h2>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <p>Don't speak about us. Don't think about us. Don't write about us. It's a secret!</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6  pull-right">
                                        <a href="#menu" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <h2>Back to menu</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section><!-- /.about-section -->    
                            <section id="contact-section" class="inactive">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="black-bg col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <h2 class="text-center">Contact Us</h2>

                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                            <p>Donec at felis nec orci dapibus consectetur. <a href="#">Integer</a> hendrerit aliquet velit, bibendum accumsan mi. Integer volutpat in velit at tincidunt. Proin varius magna nec risus accumsan blandit. Morbi eget vestibulum nisi, vitae luctus elit. In in nulla a elit rutrum pellentesque.</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                                            <p>456 Thamine Street, Digital Estate, Yangon 10630, Myanmar</p>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6  pull-right">
                                        <a href="#menu" class="change-section">
                                            <div class="black-bg btn-menu">
                                                <h2>Back to menu</h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>   


                                    </div>
                                </div>



                        </div>
                </div>



            </div><!-- /#main-wrapper -->

            <div id="preloader">
                <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
            </div><!-- /#preloader -->

            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/templatemo_script.js"></script>

        </body> 
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't escape strings that you're going to use as bind variables, else they'll end up being double-escaped, because binding escapes automatically

Comment: I see. Will delete the escape string then. Thanks for telling!

Comment: Still looking for an answer to why it does not work.

Comment: Why is your form action empty?

Comment: Because the action is happening on the same page, no need to send the request somewhere else or to itself. Trust me, I have tried with different options in form action without success.

Comment: Use echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; it's already much cleaner. Does the form reset or refresh?

Comment: Where will I input that echo?
The form reset itself. Just as I mentioned in my first post;)

Comment: In your form action, <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> .

Comment: The form still resets itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the binding try

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

instead of

```
$bind_result = $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately I got this error from switching code:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in

Comment: Try bind_param instaed of bindParam

Comment: I did, and got this warning: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in